# Update Registry file content in WSO2 EI 6.1.1 dynamically

Tags: wso2, registry, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am storing config file in **Config registry** like below.

[image: Config Registry File]

My use case here is, need to update **accessToken** tag content from wso2 ei service,because it expires within an hour. how can i pass regenerated accesstoken to this file?

```
    <!-- Reading config registry file content -->
    <property name="ZohoAppConfig" expression="get-property('registry','conf:/ZohoConfig/ZohoAppConfigFile.xml')" scope="default" type="OM" />
           <property description="accessToken" expression="$ctx:ZohoAppConfig//*[local-name()='accessToken']" name="accessToken" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="refreshToken" expression="$ctx:ZohoAppConfig//*[local-name()='refreshToken']" name="refreshToken" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="AllPortalsEP" expression="$ctx:ZohoAppConfig//*[local-name()='AllPortals']" name="uri.var.AllPortalsEP" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="===ZohoAppConfig===" expression="get-property('ZohoAppConfig')"/>
                <property expression="get-property('accessToken')" name="===accessToken===="/>
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.AllPortalsEP')" name="===uri.var.AllPortalsEP===="/>
            </log>
<!-- Need to update registry content here -->
```

Awaiting for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your ZohoAppConfig, for example using enrich mediator:

```
<enrich>
   <source clone="true" property="someNewAccesToken" type="property"/>
   <target action="replace" xpath="$ctx:ZohoAppConfig//accessToken" type="custom" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
</enrich>
```

This will update in your property ZohoAppConfig the token. Next to store back to registry you need use property:

```
<property expression="$ctx:ZohoAppConfig" name="conf:/ZohoConfig/ZohoAppConfigFile.xml"
        scope="registry" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

That should works in 6.1.1, I tested it on 6.3.0. but that way is caching the read in memory for 15sec, what could be in some cases problematic.
Another way is to store using **script mediator**, and set the cacheDuration to 0:

```
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[
mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource('conf:/ZohoConfig/ZohoAppConfigFile.xml',mc.getProperty('sample'));
var regEntry = mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().getRegistryEntry('conf:/ZohoConfig/ZohoAppConfigFile.xml');
regEntry.setCachableDuration(0);
mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateRegistryEntry(regEntry);
]]></script>
```

I have described it much more with an example, along with some encountered problem [here](https://devintegra.com/read-modify-write-wso2-enterprise-integrator-registry)